# CoreData: Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel. nil is an illegal URL parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Our live app in Appstore crashes with the following reason

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
CoreData: Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel. nil is an illegal URL parameter
```

Here is the corresponding code to that.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"DBResources" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSURL *modelURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"Profile" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

I did the basic check ups like making sure our momd file has the same name and its part of the resources.

- The weird part is it crashes only on iPhone 5,5c,4s (basically all armv7s) architectures with iOS 10 and above.
- The same version/build number i uploaded in Hockeyapp and Testflight internal does not crash

Any reasons why it would crash from Appstore only? 
Any reasons why it would crash on those devices and not iphone 5s and above?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I wonder if it could be app thinning somehow? I think there's a way to take an archive of your app and produce a variant for a given device. You could then open up the bundle and see if the momd is present in the proper location. The only other thing I can think of would be case-sensitivity, but that shouldn't affect devices differently.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the cause of this *is* "app thinning".

We just ran into a case where the presence of an 'arm64' entry in our framework's resource .bundle info.plist (as the architecture) caused ONLY armv7s devices to have the bundle stripped in the final, installed IPA.

As the architecture is not needed for the resources (and specifically here the mom/momd file), removing that architecture entry from the .bundle info.plist solves the problem.

It turns up in app store releases because of the thinning done behind the scenes, and will not generally occur when deploying via Hockey/Fabric.

Hope this helps - @neelesh I know your question was ages ago.